# pasar estuctura de formulario a json

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

Necesito pasar esta estructura de formulario a `json`:

```
<form id="#" name="formulario" action="#" method="#">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <section class="container-fluid" style="word-break: break-all;  word-wrap: break-word;" id="resultado">
      <article>
        <div class="container-fluid form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usr">Contraseña</label>
              <input type="password" size="30" maxlength="56" placeholder="entra" class="form-group" name="input_contra1" id="input_contra1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <div class="container-fluid form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <p>eres</p>
            <form>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checko1" id="checko1" value="">1
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checko2" id="checko2" value="">2
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checko3" id="checko3" value="">3
                </label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <div class="container-fluid form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <form>
            <label for="sel1">deporte </label>
              <select class="form-control-static" id="sel1">
                <option name="select1" id="select1">tenis</option>
                <option name="select2" id="select2">padel</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="oculto" class="text-center oculto">
      <button type="submit" id="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm boton">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

por ejemplo quiero del input contraseña:

```
{
  label:"Contraseña",
  input: {
    "type":"password,
    "size": 30,
    "maxlength":56,
    "placeholdre":"entra"
  }
}
```

del checkbox:

su contenido del label las opciones que da...

**¿sería con serializeobject?**

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.SO], puede que le interese leer el [tour], puede tratar de mejorar su respuesta mirando [ask], es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada por estar basada en opiniones.

Comment: Al hacer una pregunta es bueno que siempre coloques lo que has intentado así se te ayuda, si haces un pregunta que la respuesta te la puede dar google sera cerrada tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

**Jquery** puede hacer eso

```js
  function showValues() {
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    $("#results").text( str );
  }
  $("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']").on("click", showValues );
  $("select").on("change", showValues );
  showValues();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>serialize demo</title>
  <style>
  body, select {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  form {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<form>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>
 
  <br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>
 
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
 
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
 
<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, añadiendo el tipo de codificación al formulario en la cabecera, te dejo un ejemplo y a continuación la documentacion:

```
<form enctype='application/json'>
    <input name='name' value='Bender'>
    <select name='hind'>
        <option selected>Bitable</option>
        <option>Kickable</option>
    </select>
    <input type='checkbox' name='shiny' checked>
</form>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Depende de lo que necesites hacer.

Otra opción a lo que ya te mencionaron, lo puedes hacer a través de JQuery, es una API que mejora la implementación de JavaScript, permitiendote realizar funcionalidades mas concisas (acceso al DOM, eventos, etc.) que JavaScript.

Te dejo la documentación de Jquery: [JQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Ahora, lo que necesita lo puedes hacer a través de esta API, como en el siguiente ejemplo: [Form to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

JQuery Showcase: [JQuery Demos](https://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Espero te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: busco pues eso henerar un json a partir de un formulario por ejemplo sacar el contenido del label del input tl type, plaholder...